# Hiding TinyNav Submenu

Tags: javascript, css, drop-down-menu, menu, submenu

I'm using TinyNav on my website, which works great, however we have a deep menu system meaning the tinynav dropdown is huge.
I've been trying to find a way of hiding all sub-menus but to no avail.

I have tried using media queries eg:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
#tinynav1 > li > ul > li, #tinynav1 > li > ul > li > a {
display:none
}
#tinynav1 > li > ul {
display:none;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing i see in this code what you should do ad a semikolon after none (;).
But is to less code too help you :) 
Do you have a link to the page? Or can you build the navigation on http://jsfiddle.net

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {

    #tinynav1 li ul li, #tinynav1 li ul li  a {
       display:none;
    }
    #tinynav1 li ul {
       display:none;
    }

 }
```

Comment: That can't work. Cause form 0 till 800 px you have a Quicknavigation in it. You musst put this site's out in the php were the quicknavigation is build. What kind of CMS do you use?

Comment: I don't understand Javascript but I have tried playing a little with (but subsequently breaking) the tinynav.js file.
Could there be a way of changing the code so it doesn't show submenus?
I'm using dreamweaver.

Comment: No the problem is the media-queries. You use 2 diffrent menu types. the first is a UL LI navigation and from dvice width 0 till 800 px you have a quicknavigation in it.

Comment: Yes Tinynav (http://tinynav.viljamis.com/)

My question is if it's possible to only view the top menu items in the tinynav menu.